# Wavelet transform in R or python using a finite dataset

Tags: python, r, wavelet

I am trying to implement a wavelet transform similar to that of Bardshaw and Spies (1992) in R or Python (...or even Matlab if needs be!).  I am currently using the Passage2 software package (http://www.passagesoftware.net/) but would like to recreate this in one of the above packages so as to have more flexibility over output and analysis.

In more detail, I would like to perform a (I think continuous) wavelet transform using the mexican hat wavelet over a set of observations with a **finite** length from which I would like to calculate the scale-variance.  The packages I have tried in R (wmtsa, waveslim, rwave) and Python (scipy.signal.cwt) assume the data is circular (I think this is the right term) and therefore the output does not taper as wavelet scale increases.

Even when assuming the data is circular the output from Passage2 and R are VERY different.

The idea of wavelets is very new to me but I am willing to learn! Any help most gratefully received.

Thanks, Phil

Bradshaw, GA & TA Spies (1992). Characterizing canopy gap structure in forests using wavelet analysis. Journal of Ecology, 80(2), pp.205–215.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but there is supposedly a package for wavelet transform here. http://tocsy.pik-potsdam.de/wavelets/. Matlab versions can be found here: http://paos.colorado.edu/research/wavelets/software.html.

Comment: Thanks @Marcinthebox, the Matlab version is just what I needed!